Cookies available to access from isnonmia/postman but not from client side
hey i have 2 function as given below
const UserLogin = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email: req.body.email } });

    if (!user) {

      return res.status(404).json({ message: "User does not exist" });
    }

    const password = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);

    if (!password) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Incorrect password" });
    }



    const Token = createToken(user.id, user.isAdmin);
    console.log(Token)

    res.cookie('token', Token, { httpOnly: true, });


    return res.status(200).json({ message: "User logged in successfully", Token, user: { id: user.id, name: user.username, isAdmin: user.isAdmin } });

  } catch (error) {

    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
};

And have a middleware as shown below
import jsonwebtoken from 'jsonwebtoken';
const { verify } = jsonwebtoken;
import { getUser } from './token';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { compareSync } from 'bcrypt';
interface DecodedToken {
  userId: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      user?: DecodedToken | null

    }
  }
}
const isAuth = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<any> => {
  const tokenCookie = req.cookies?.token;
  console.log(tokenCookie)
  req.user = null;

  if (!tokenCookie) {
    return next();
  }

  try {
    const data = await getUser(tokenCookie);
    
    req.user = data;
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error retrieving user data:", error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
};

const restrictedTo = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    await isAuth(req, res, async () => {
      if (req.user?.isAdmin) {
    
        next();
      } else {
        return res.status(403).json({ message: "You are not allowed to do that" });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in restrictedTo middleware:", error);
   return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
};

when I try to access middle ware via Insomnia i have the cookies stored and the middleware works well.once I try to access it via the client side(react) i cant access it.tried using postman where it works well not from client side
